# Getting the value of a string being cast as a binary string

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am querying an Advantage Database Server and one of the results returns the following...

`["description" => b"My description string"]`

I'm using Laravel's Lumen framework as an api server and when I return this in a json response I got the following error.

`UnexpectedValueException in Response.php line 397:
The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.`

My question is, how to convert `b"My description string"` into a string that I can return in the response?

The server is running PHP 5.5.

Can anyone help?

Comment: `"b\"My description string\""` possibly?

Comment: @pokeybit I don't know how I would convert it to your suggestion programmatically

Comment: try utf8_encode()

Answer (score 0):

`iconv("utf-8", "utf-8//ignore", b"My description string")` seemed to do the trick!

Comment: @DanatheSane There is nothing in the answer that says "thank you".  There is no other answer to accept.  If volunteers would post their suggested solutions as answers instead of comments, then the OP could accept and upvote them.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230676/hey-you-yeah-you-post-your-answers-as-answers-not-comments/296481#296481  There is nothing wrong with the OP posting what solved the issue.

Comment: @bencarter78 a bit of explanation will benefit future SO readers.  Please improve your answer with any knowledge that you have discovered.  Reference links seems a good idea too.

Comment: I've removed my review comment. I agree with @mickmackusa, it would be helpful to explain how and why you arrived at your answer.